# How can i get output in sequence rather than random in PHP

Tags: php

Hi i have some values in 1.txt and want to show them in sequence one by one rather than random and also on click of a button not on reload. And i don't have much code on it. Can anyone help me with it please. ?

index.php:

```
<?php $lines = file('1.txt');?>   <?php echo $lines[array($lines)];?>
```

1.txt in list format vertically:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: What client-side language are you using for this?

Answer (score 0):

Writing PHP like this is bad practice:

```
<?php $lines = ...;?>   <?php echo ....;?>
```

Better write like this:

```
<?php
  $lines = ...;
  echo ...;
```

Now to your problem, you should use sort to order an array see: https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.sort.php

The best way to print an array in PHP is foreach:

```
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    echo "\n<p>" . $line; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your saying with the push of button and reload.
But this code assumes you mean, once the list has been generated keep it in the same order to this visitor.

I do that using a session variable so that even if the user reloads the page the order will be the same (for this user), but different between different users.

```
session_start();

if(empty($_session['lines'])){
    $_session['lines'] = file('1.txt');
    shuffle($_session['lines']);

}
// For debug:
echo implode("<br>\n", $_session['lines']);
```